# Problem with "ü" in jQuery mobile application on Blackberry

Tags: html, blackberry, character-encoding, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have a jQuery mobile application for Blackberry. The problem I have is the following. When I add a list item in the jQuery mobile listview with a "ü" in it all my buttons break on the page. When I click on a button I get the following message: "The protocol specified is not supported by the handheld. Please try a different URL.".

When there is no list item in the listview with a "ü" everything works as expected. I don't know if this is a problem with the jQuery mobile support on Blackberry or if it's just a Blackberry problem.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a HTML entity instead: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Code:

```
Ü   &#220;  &Uuml; // capital u, umlaut mark
ü   &#252;  &uuml; // small u, umlaut mark
```

Display:

Uppercase:

- Ü    Ü  Ü

Lowercase:

- ü    ü  ü

UTF-8 Encoding: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ (Note: You can click different display options)

```
U+00DC  Ü   c3 9c   // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
U+00FC  ü   c3 bc   // LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
```

UPDATE:

For Russian Character Sets did you try these:

- charset="windows-1251"
- charset="UTF-16"
- charset=ISO-8859-1"

Other Sources to try:

- http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Alternative problems:

So this could be related depending on how you store the data.

- A: Is everything hard coded? The I would suggest changing the charset in the header
- B: Database driven? I would suggestion checking on the encoding your storing the data as.

  - Related Links:

    - [MySQL collation to store multilingual data of unknown language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288006/mysql-collation-to-store-multilingual-data-of-unknown-language)
    - http://united-states.linuxotic.com/documentation/oracle/database/10.1/server.101/b10749/ch6unicode.htm

Comment: I discovered that the problem is not only with the ü. The problem also exists with the russian characterset. I tried changing the encoding of the page. But nothing works. Anyway thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Make sure your files are UTF-8 encoded or your scripts produce UTF-8 conform output. I've used Notepad++ to convert my files...