# Romanian diacritics in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, collation

I'm inputting **Romanian diacritics** in some of my database fields and they are not showing up as expected.

- Romanian diacritics are: `Ă ă Â â Î î Ș ș Ț ț`
- The whole line above displays as: `Ä‚ Äƒ Ã‚ Ã¢ ÃŽ Ã® È˜ È™ Èš È›`
- When I save a word containing `ã` it displays as `Ã£`

I'd like to know what collation should I set for the table for this to work

**or**

just stop using them all together and just save them as normal letters when they are inputed, in which case:

**Inputing**

- ã would get saved as a
- â would get saved as a
- î would get saved as i
- ș would get saved as s
- ț would get saved as t

Any thoughts? I've tried setting multiple `utf-8` as collation for the table, including utf_8_unicode_ci, as well as `latin1` but that doesn't solve the problem.

Current `collation` set for the tables in question is `utf_8_general_ci`

Using MysQL.

Please do let me know in a comment if I left anything out and you require more details

Comment: Have you tried utf_8_unicode_ci?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Hi, thanks for the interest. Yes, I've tried it, same problem.

Comment: How about utf_16_unicode_ci? Also, what encoding is used by the web page that submits the data?

Comment: @SloanThrasher just tried it, nope. I'm submitting through phpmyadmin, in the cpanel of the hosting. Not sure how to answer your 2nd question, tables are set to `utf8_general_ci` while InnoDB line below the tables says this: `InnoDB latin1_swedish_ci` (Default) and `Server connection collation ` is set to `utf_8_general_ci`

Comment: checkout this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288006/mysql-collation-to-store-multilingual-data-of-unknown-language

Comment: I just checked my copy of phpAdmin, and the page uses utf8, and so it may be storing it correctly, but messing it up on display. If you have PHP, write a simple page to retrieve and display the value, and set the page character set  to unicode.

Comment: Thanks but neither utf8_general_ci nor utf8_unicode_ci solve the problem. I understand the difference stated there but they don't seem to work for romanian. I've also loaded the data in multiple browser, from phpmyadmin using the cpanel and in a software written in Delphi(in a TMemo) with no luck. I've also changed default for whole db from latin1 swedish to both of those utf8 options and that doesn't do it either. MysQL workbench displays it the same also.

Comment: I just did a simple test with a table with 2 columns, one as utf8 and unicode, and another as utf_16 and unicode. The first column stores the data correctly, but is displays as in your question. The second column displays correctly, but only when the web page encoding is set to utf16 and unicode.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Indeed. I've just set the database, table AND fields to utf16_unicode_ci and they both display and store properly. Thanks, if you don't mind writting this up as an answer so I can accept for you, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ã it displays as Ã£" -- That's Mojibake; see [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Mojibake is a common problem; utf16 is *not* the solution.  (It may have *accidentally* worked.)

Answer (score 1):

Set the table to utf16_unicode_ci, and that should do the trick.

I did a simple test with a table with 2 columns, one as utf8 and unicode, and another as utf_16 and unicode. The first column stores the data correctly, but is displays as in your question. The second column displays correctly, but only when the web page encoding is set to utf16 and unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using MySQL. What about **utf8_romanian_ci** (introduced in MySQL 6.0.4)?

On the other hand, you might use **utf8_bin**, for WordPress (which seems glued to MySQL 5).

Collation charts: http://collation-charts.org

I found some answers here, too: [utf8_bin vs utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929836/utf8-bin-vs-utf-unicode-ci)