# What mysql collation should I use for Vietnamese, Russian and English database

Tags: mysql, collation

I am working on wordpress and wamp combination. WordPress will be used for online shop/delivery service, and will be initially in 3 languages English, Russian and Vietnamese.

For MySql database I am thinking I should use `utf16_general_ci` collation which should cover all the characters in languages above, still I have never worked on a project like this.

**Which collision should I choose not to run into weird sorting issues later on?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL collation to store multilingual data of unknown language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288006/mysql-collation-to-store-multilingual-data-of-unknown-language)

Comment: @JorgeCampos languages are known and listed in my case.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed since unknown languages covers any listed language I thought that it would apply. But like the automatic comment states "*Possible* duplicate". Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## utf8mb4

It supports all the languages you named, and practically all other languages on earth.

It's the [default character set / collation in MySQL 8.0, and it's now faster than utf8](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-when-to-use-utf8mb3-over-utf8mb4/).

It's the [default character set in Wordpress 4.2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/).